# Adding jquery ui to intellij idea project

Tags: intellij-idea, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to add jquery ui to my project, i have added, jquery-ui.js, jquery.js and jquery-ui.css to my project but idea does not recognize jquery-ui functions(my problem is with dialog() function).
i thought this is intellij idea's problem and ran my project, but does not what i wanted. could you please tell me what is wrong with my code.
here is my code:

$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });

Answer (score 0):

Before you 'open' the dialog, you must 'prepare' it - assuming that in your index.html you have the following tags:

```
<div id="msg_dialog" hidden></div>
<div>
    <button onclick="showDialog(); return false;">click me!</button>
</div>
```

then in your javascript you should have:

```
function showDialog() {
    $('msg_dialog').dialog('open');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#msg_dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                Dismiss: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
});
```

or something to that effect.